# I want to write from AWS API Gateway to RDS directly

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to post the json data by ajax to AWS API Gateway, and write to RDS directly.

I have to input the mapping template to API Gateway setting.
But I can not found the sample for write to RDS.
If you know the sample or tutorial, or will not you tell us?

This is the code for write to DynamoDB.
I run the same process to RDS.

```js
{ 
    "TableName": "$stageVariables.tablename",
    "Item": {
        "id": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
            },
        "url": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.url')"
            },
        "event_type": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.event_type')"
            },
        "data": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.data')"
            },
        "created_at": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.event_datetime')"
        }
    }
}
```

I write that AWS Service is RDS to Integrated Request Setting.
But Not in RDS instance name and table name.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible, authentication towards classic (non-Aurora) RDS doesn't happen with IAM. Alternatively you could invoke a Lambda function that does the writing to RDS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lambda in between so that you can make a query or call a procedure directly to RDS.